# Spring database type NONE and external custom properties file

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm new to Spring. I got a project and am trying to run it with IntelliJ Idea (the one who gave me project access used Eclipse).

The JDBC driver is set in a custom properties file, called test.application.properties.

It gives me the following error:

```
2018-01-17 14:30:33.556  INFO 9804 --- [           main] i.test.TestApplication: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-17 14:30:33.638  INFO 9804 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@49c43f4e: startup date [Wed Jan 17 14:30:33 BRST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-17 14:30:36.657  INFO 9804 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-17 14:30:36.683  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-01-17 14:30:36.685  INFO 9804 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2018-01-17 14:30:36.880  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-17 14:30:36.881  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3248 ms
2018-01-17 14:30:37.379  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.383  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.383  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.383  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.383  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.383  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.383  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.384  INFO 9804 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.442  WARN 9804 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'createNamedParameterJdbcTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2018-01-17 14:30:37.446  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-01-17 14:30:37.472  INFO 9804 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-17 14:30:37.477 ERROR 9804 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The error seems to be with the JDBC driver...

I'm trying to set Run/debug configuration's program arguments with `--spring.config.location=classpath:/src/main/resources/test.application.properties` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got this before and had to add in this property after a lot of research:

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.Data
SourceAutoConfiguration`

I got it when I was trying to use spring boot without a web service.  Never got to the underlying reason that this happened though.

Give it a shot and see if it mitigates the error.